# Spark drop colums with 0 or NaN

Tags: apache-spark

If I have a `DF` with standard deviations how do I drop these columns or avoid processing them or se it in the model building (in a semi automatic way)

So for example I would like to

1. find columns with many missing values, nulls or NaN
2. find columns with low correlation (for instance pearson)  with the dependent var
3. remove all columns from (1) and ten lowest from (2)

Comment: related 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html

Comment: Could you explain yourself? your question is a bit ambiguous

Comment: concerning (1) you can use the DataFrameNAFunctions : http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions e.g df.na.drop()

Comment: (2) isn't that straightforward and I don't have a dev environment to test now. I'll be glad too look into it tomorrow.

Comment: thanks, I didnt find the na funtions yesterday

Comment: na functions works on a row level not column level

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to drop columns that have `null` values in it:

```
val df = Seq(
  (Option(1),Option(11),None), (Option(2), None, Option(222))
).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

// +----+----+----+
// |col1|col2|col3|
// +----+----+----+
// |   1|  11|null|
// |   2|null| 222|
// +----+----+----+

val nullCount = udf[Int,Any](any => if (any == null) 1 else 0)

val columnNullCounts = df.select(
  df.columns.map(c => nullCount(col(c)) as c):_*
).agg(
  sum(df.columns(0)) as df.columns(0),
  df.columns.slice(1, df.columns.length).map(c => sum(c) as c):_*
).collect.apply(0).toSeq.toArray

df.select(df.columns.zip(columnNullCounts).filter(v => v._2 == 0).map(c => col(c._1)):_*)

// +----+
// |col1|
// +----+
// |   1|
// |   2|
// +----+
```

Note that all the major complexity in the above code is because I made it generic to work with an `DataFrame`. It uses `DataFrame.columns` to build its queries dynamically. If you don't want to check every column, you could rewrite it to hard code values -- but this should be enough to get you going.

Comment: Maybe use df.stat.freqItems instead?

Comment: That doesn't really get him what he wants, does it?